# How to encrypt or decrypt string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to encrypt and decrypt string in javascript using following code.But i got crypto js is not defined.

```js
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", "Secret Passphrase");
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, "Secret Passphrase");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is the script tag for cryptojs before your javascript?

Comment: you need to convert it to tostring

Comment: I placed your logic in a snippet where it appears to work (although the response appears to be objects not strings). Check to ensure you're including the crypto script in the page *before* you run your own logic.

Comment: You're not working with the responses from the method calls properly. See the AES section of the documentation about 2/3 of the way down this page: https://github.com/brix/crypto-js

Answer (score 11):

Works fine for me.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xbk736br/

```js
// Encrypt
var ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt('my message', 'secret key 123');

// Decrypt
var bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertext.toString(), 'secret key 123');
var plaintext = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

console.log(plaintext);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are building a react or nodejs app, you can simply use this library [ncrypt-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ncrypt-js) to encrypt and decrypt your data.

[See example on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-cdn-1vcpo)

usage:

es5

```
var ncrypt = require('ncrypt-js'); // or var { encrypt, decrypt } = require('ncrypt-js);

let encryptData = ncrypt.encrypt('super secret data', 'secret_key');
// or
// let encryptData = encrypt('super secret data', 'secret_key');

console.log(encryptData); // 11ab949601eb136f58ac3fe846e30d76.f9ce133b20adc35eef32af95957547abbb6fbfc5cb91cd14f5b0a088bd031883963cde1a56fd62fe2aeb75451a065d21
var decryptedData = ncrypt.decrypt(encryptData);
// or
// var decryptedData = decrypt(encryptData);

console.log(decryptedData); // super secret data
```

es6

```
import ncrypt from 'ncrypt-js'; // or import { encrypt, decrypt } from 'ncrypt-js';

const encryptData = ncrypt.encrypt('super secret data', 'secret_key');
// or
// const encryptData = encrypt('super secret data', 'secret_key');

console.log(encryptData); // 11ab949601eb136f58ac3fe846e30d76.f9ce133b20adc35eef32af95957547abbb6fbfc5cb91cd14f5b0a088bd031883963cde1a56fd62fe2aeb75451a065d21
const decryptedData = ncrypt.decrypt(encryptData);
// or
// const decryptedData = decrypt(encryptData);

console.log(decryptedData); // super secret data
```

Answer (score 2):

`encrypted.toString()` will return the correct string value.

```js
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", "Secret Passphrase");
alert(encrypted.toString());
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, "Secret Passphrase");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js"></script>
```

Comment: while encrypting? I am not getting any error actually.

Comment: Double check whether your code is placed correctly in `<script>` tag