# How do I encrypt and decrypt a string using a function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, encryption, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am currently working on a web project mainly comprised of HTML, CSS, and Javascript (vanilla). It involves a basic login/sign-in system which will be used to handle accounts. The actual project itself is quite complex but to summarise it is a live messaging system. For this, I am planning to store data such as passwords, messages, usernames, personal info, etc. on a cloud database (Firebase). To secure these sorts of data, I am planning to use end-to-end encryption. This means data gets stored in its encrypted form on the cloud server, making it impossible to read for anyone like me who has direct access to the server. I am currently working on the sign-in stage of my project, and I have managed to get a few strings on their details, these are:

- Full Name
- Date of Birth
- Gender
- Username
- Email Address
- Verified Password

All I want to do now is to simply encrypt these strings using a simple function in which I can pass the string through as the only parameter and for it to return an encrypted string perhaps with a key to decrypt it. And also a function to do the reverse (return the original string from an encrypted one). Can anyone make one for me or provide a library for this?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at crypto-js

Comment: Can you please explain what that is

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js an npm package providing crypto functions

Comment: The Question Already Got an Answer here- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18279141/javascript-string-encryption-and-decryption

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to encrypt or decrypt string in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50449367/how-to-encrypt-or-decrypt-string-in-javascript)